# Vbs Make a text file with text written in it

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a VbScript program which will create a text file and write the information given to it from an input box.

for example:

```
firstNameInput = inputbox("Enter your name")
lastNameInput = inputbox("Enter your last name")
eMailInput = inputbox("Enter your e-mail adress")
numberInput = inputbox("Enter your number")
```

Now the rest of the code has to create a text file with these information written in it

so the text document would look something like this:

```
Bob Marley --- Bobiscool@gmail.com --- 0918273645
```

If you can help, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to create a text file stream and write to it:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fileStream
Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Foo.txt")
fileStream.WriteLine "First name: " & firstNameInput
fileStream.WriteLine "Last name: " & lastNameInput
' and so on...
fileStream.Close
```

This is documented on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Thanks but it has an error, it says expected end of statement, I don't know how to fix it because I'm very new to programming. sorry.

Comment: @Ruan Sorry, I forgot the parenthesis for the `CreateTextFile` call. Try again with that change.

Comment: It goes in the program but gives an error as soon as i type my first name, it says variable is undefined: 'firstNameInput'

Comment: Okay wait, I got it working, all i did was `Dim firstNameInput` `Dim lastNameInput` etc. thanks for your help