# Creating a text file throws "file path unaccesible" vbs

Tags: file, vbscript, runtime-error

I am trying to create an installer for my app in vbs but when I try to create a file for the said app it throws "file path unaccesible" on line 21 character 13 I do not know why it does this. I have checkedother ways to do it and they resulted in the same outcome ex. [Vbs Make a text file with text written in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466765/vbs-make-a-text-file-with-text-written-in-it). I have also checked if the path name existed and it does.

This is what I tried:

```
Set ob = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

dim result
result = MsgBox("Do you want to install the sleep startup programm?", 4, "Installer")

If result=6 Then
BrowseForFile()
End If

Function BrowseForFile()
Dim Shell : Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim File : Set File = Shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder:", &H4210)
    If File Is Nothing Then
        BrowseFolder = ""
    Else
        BrowseForFile = file.self.Path
        result = MsgBox("Do you want the files contained in this folder to be executed whenever you wake up your computer?" & vbCrLf & "Folder Path:" & BrowseForFile, 4, "Question Prompt")
        If result=6 Then
            MsgBox("Installing...")

            Dim FSO
            Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            UsrPrfl = ob.expandenvironmentstrings("%UserProfile%")
            Set OutPutFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(UsrPrfl & "Desktop\test.txt", True)
            OutPutFile.WriteLine("Writing text to a file")
            OutPutFile.Close
            Set FSO = Nothing

        Else
            BrowseForFile()
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can't use environment variables in VBScript the same way you can in batch files. Use the [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/c1c1f29c-2a30-46a1-bae7-c17f8af55a19.asp) method to set a variable and then concatenate that with the rest of the path using `&`. And it's better to expand `%UserProfile%` instead of assuming the profile is in `C:\Users`. Also, after writing to the file, be sure to close the file with `OutPutFile.Close`.

Comment: okay thanks im going to try it and i will tell you if it works thanks

Comment: Also add a `True` to [CreateTextFile](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/62045015-70d8-4308-a74a-71de0166e6ec.asp) so that it will overwrite an existing file.

Comment: I just modified it altho it still doesn't work

Comment: You just need to check your strings using `Wscript.Echo` or `MsgBox`. Then, most of the issues will be readily apparent. Your `UsrPrfl` variable does not have a trailing backslash, therefore, `"Desktop\test.txt"` should be `"\Desktop\test.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! if you want you can write this as an answer ill mark it as the answer thanks!!!

Comment: It's all stuff that's been covered before and SO is set up for one issue per question/answer. We touched on several issues here. Happy to help though. BTW, this is one where you could have pasted your code into ChatGPT and it probably would have found the errors. It would be interesting to try.